# Codifferential of k-th exterior power endmorphism applied to differential form $\delta(\wedge^p A\alpha)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $(M,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth Riemannian manifold without boundary. Given an endomorphism $A(x) : \sf T_x^*M \to \sf T_x^*M$ on the cotangent bundle, we can extend $A$ to an endomorphism on the $p$-th exterior power acting on a $p$-form $\alpha$ by
\begin{align*}
\wedge^p A : \wedge^p \sf T_x^*M &\to \wedge^p \sf T_x^*M\\
\wedge^p A(\alpha_1 \wedge ... \wedge \alpha_p) &:= A\alpha_1 \wedge ... \wedge A\alpha_p.
\end{align*}
How can we make sense of the codifferential
$$\delta(\wedge^p A\alpha)?$$
The problem is that $\dim \wedge^p \sf T_x^*M = {n \choose p}$, unlike the case $\dim \wedge^n \sf T_x^*M = {n \choose n} = 1$, where $\wedge^n A$ must act as a multiplication operator, i.e. the determinant.

But $\delta$ is not a derivation of the algebra, i.e. there is [no nice version of the Leibniz rule](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/the-codifferential/). Either using the definition of $\delta = \ast \, \mathbf d \, \ast $ directly or using the definition that it is the formal adjoint of the exterior derivative $\mathbf d$, the question boils down to: What is the exterior derivative of this $k$-th power endomorphism $\wedge^p A$?